# Does ASF Apply to the Initiate of the Sevenfold Veil Class Abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I was recently looking at the Initiate of the Sevenfold Veil class and was looking at its class abilities and started to wonder, if they are equivalent to Xth Level spells.(X being a different number for each Veil.) are they vulnerable to Arcane Spell Failure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. [Arcane Spell Failure](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/sorcererWizard.htm#arcaneSpellsAndArmor) is explicitly for arcane spells.

> Even if a wizard or sorcerer is wearing armor with which he or she is proficient, however, it might still interfere with spellcasting...
>
> Armor restricts the complicated gestures that a wizards or sorcerer must make while casting any spell that has a somatic component (most do). The armor and shield descriptions list the arcane spell failure chance for different armors and shields.

Spell-like abilities aren't subject to it, which is what those class abilities would fall under. Most of the magical type are either (Sp) or (Su). The spell level equivalent is for any effects that might depend on spell level, like if the opponent has a *[globe of invulnerability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/globeOfInvulnerability.htm)* active or anything else where spell/effect level would matter.

Besides, spell level has nothing to do with ASF. The spell's components (verbal, material, **somatic**) do, or more specifically whether the spell has an **S** component does.

Comment: the Spell Level equivalencies were not part of the assumption but more the trigger for the thought that lead to the question.

Answer (score 3):

No, they do not suffer Arcane Spell Failure. Despite any equivalencies that could be found, creating a Warding (and thus, imbuing it with a veil) is a Spell-like Ability. [SLAs don't have somatic components](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spellLikeAbilities) and [only Somatic components](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/equipment/armor.htm#arcaneSpellFailure) of (some) arcane spells enforce ASF.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while, but if memory serves the only Spell-Like Abilities that are subject to arcane spell failure from armor are everything the warlock does. Why the designers hated warlocks so much will be a question for history, but you should know that there is no Arcane Spell Failure chance from any Extraordinary, Supernatural or Spell-Like Ability unless specifically stated right there in the class description. If you don't see it in the IotSV description (and check errata too), then you can use those with no failure chance.